# How to get max value after inserting as a join query

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `idt_lookup`(`idt_resources`, `idt_lookup_name`, `idt_lookup_tbl_name`, `idt_lookup_key_col`, `idt_lookup_val_col`, `last_upd_by`, `last_upd_datetime_utc`) VALUES ('" + resourceId + "','" + roltbl + "','" + roltbl + "','" + rolid + "','" + rolname + "','1','" + date1 + "')

SELECT MAX(`idt_lookup_id`) AS maxid FROM `idt_lookup
```

How can i join these two queries. Is this possible?

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: Is `idt_lookup_id` an auto increment column?  What language, if any, are you using?

Comment: Do note that concatenating SQL strings will leave you vulnerable for injection attacks. Please use parameters. And while you cannot combine these queries, you can of course send them at the same time to the server separated by a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Try Sample Query:-

```
$insertQuery = "
    INSERT INTO owner_business_media
        (business_id, sequence, type, filename, title, secret)
    SELECT
        '".intval($_GET['businessid'])."',
        (SELECT MAX(obm.sequence)+1 FROM owner_business_media obm WHERE obm.business_id=".intval($_GET['businessid']).") AS next,
        '$type', 
        '$fullfile', 
        '$filename', 
        '1'
";
```

Hope this will help...!!